# What and how to test in a Web site?

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, web

I want to know about the validation that a component or a text field a website should have.
Please let me know the list of things that are needed to be tested in a text box (password, email id, search box etc...)

Comment: How many years do you have to test it? I'm only half joking here, by the way. What you need to test depends on what the text box is supposed to do. Without that information, someone could say "Everything" and be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far too broad to give you a specific answer.

But these might help, and might help you narrow your question down a bit:
http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/general-input-tests-for-strings.html
http://www.allthingsquality.com/search/label/Test%20Data

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, its more like how do I test in general?
(If you are new with testing I suggest read up on [Software Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) or take a [Training](https://www.google.com/search?q=software%20testing%20training).)

Lets say your website was a car, what are the most important (must test) features on a car?

- That it starts
- That the breaks work
- That warnings lights work

What can go wrong

- When you hit a wall
- Run out of gas
- Riding on a soft road

What things do you need to verify at minimum before we send the car out to its users?

I think you should be able to come up with requirements for your website and its input fields. For websites the most important thing is what the users want to accomplish [end-to-end](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7035/end-to-end-test) and that it works on [the most commonly used browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp).

Here is a blogpost to get you started on the input fields: http://test-givethebest.blogspot.nl/2011/08/test-give-best-input-data-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check

- For Different Input Combinations / Tests - Test Heuristics Cheat Sheet - http://testobsessed.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/testheuristicscheatsheetv1.pdf